# Where does VirtualBox (host application) store logs?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox, logging

I have a super weird issue which I've been trying to investigate for hours now. When I attempt to open VirtualBox on a Windows 10 host, nothing happens. A couple of VirtualBox processes appear in Task Manager but no GUI opens.

I've tried reinstalling; rebooting; installing several different versions; manually deleting all registry keys related to VirtualBox; running as administrator... nothing works. It worked fine for months but suddenly doesn't anymore.

I'm absolutely stumped so the only other thing I can do is try and look at logs to understand what's going on.

Windows Event Viewer doesn't have any relevant events to show so I was hoping that VirtualBox itself has log files somewhere. Where can I find them?

Comment: I’m posting this as a comment (rather than as an answer) because it’s not, strictly speaking, an answer to your question.  But — the behavior you describe sounds like that of a program whose window got moved off the screen, and “remembers” that position, and is trying to return to that position (so it’s running, but you can’t see it).  After you start the program, press (Alt)+(Space).  This should invoke the “Restore” / “Move” / “Size” / “Minimize” / “Maximize” / “Close” menu (which might or might not appear on the screen). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … Press ``M`` (for “Move”); the cursor should turn into a compass rose (i.e., a ‘+’ sign with four arrows).  Press the “Left” / “Down” / “Up” / “Right” (cursor movement) keys a bunch of times.  If the window appears, move it where you want it and press “Enter”.  If nothing visible happens, give up and press “Esc”.

Answer (score 0):

You can find logs related to virtualbox here :

```
C:\ProgramData\VirtualBox
```